# $\epsilon_{i_1...i_n}\frac{1}{1-a_1a_{i_1}}\cdots\frac{1}{1-a_na_{i_n}} = \frac{\prod_{ i,j, i<j }(a_i-a_j)^2}{\prod_{ i,j. i\leq j}(a_ia_j-1)^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's define an $n\times n$ marix $A$ with elements $A_{ij} = \frac{1}{1-a_ia_j}$ ,

Is the following identity true?
$$\det A=  \epsilon_{i_1i_2...i_n}\frac{1}{1-a_1a_{i_1}}\cdots\frac{1}{1-a_na_{i_n}} = \frac{\prod_{{\substack{
   i,j \\
   i<j
  }}}(a_i-a_j)^2}{\prod_{{\substack{
   i,j \\
   i\leq j
  }}}(a_ia_j-1)^2}$$

**Note that repeated indices are summed in the middle expression.**

I tried $n=2,3,4$, they are of this form. Therefore I guessed and wrote down the above identity but did not prove it. The denominator on the right-hand side is obvious while I got a messy expression at the numerator.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: any comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : multiply each column $C_i$ of $A$ by $a_i$ and this will give you a [Cauchy matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Cauchy_determinants)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have proved it by induction.